# Caption text and label size to only one figure

Tags: floats, captions, fontsize

Could I change caption text size and label size to only one figure?

I've seen in other questions that:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,labelfont=footnotesize}
```

can be used to change sizes in captions, but that is for the whole document and I would like to do this for only one figure; could this be possible?

Best regards and thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local changes to a specific caption can be done within the `figure` or `table` environment, if `\captionsetup` is used in the relevant environment. See the example of the 2nd `figure` environment -- the change of settings does not leak outside and has no effect on the third `figure` caption.

Make sure to remove the optional argument `[figure]` or `[table]`, otherwise `caption` complains and does not apply the local changes at all.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Foo figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize,labelfont=footnotesize}
\caption{Foobar figure}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\caption{other Foo figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An explanation why `\captionsetup[figure}{...}` does not work when used within a figure: `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` gets executed at (every) `\begin{figure}`, therefore this does not have any effect when used *after* `\begin{figure}`, and therefore local settings (done within the figure) will override settings done with `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` in the preamble.