# How to change the text size and line gap in caption of the figure?

Tags: captions

I'm trying to change the text size and the gap between lines of caption of figure but it's not working.

I have tried these solution given by people in these questions 
[How to adjust the gap between figure and caption within the same subfloat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386013/how-to-adjust-the-gap-between-figure-and-caption-within-the-same-subfloat)

[Caption text and label size to only one figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326311/caption-text-and-label-size-to-only-one-figure)

But none of them is working for me. A little help would be appreciated.

There's a list of packages i'm using.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}





\begin{figure}[H]
   \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{-2cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{airmass_vs_ew_4854_87.pdf}
   \caption{\small The plot shows the difference of Equivalent width measured in two cases vs. Airmass. The red line shows the best linear fit.} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{airmass_vs_ew_by_ew4854_87.pdf}
   \caption{\small The plot shows ratio of the difference of Equivalent width  measured in two cases with Equivalent width measured using 2D blaze corrected spectra vs. Airmass. The red line shows the best linear fit.}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal working example?

Comment: yeah ofcourse. @Bernard

Comment: Let me guess: you want the caption to be typeset in `\small``  size, not `scriptsize`  and the interline stretch to be  normal (1), not 1.5?

Comment: yeah exactly. That's what i want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5} 
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
%\usepackage[justification=centering,font=scriptsize]{caption}




\begin{figure}[H]
   \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{-2cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
   \caption{\fontsize{8}{7}\selectfont The plot shows the difference of Equivalent width measured in two cases vs. Airmass. The red line shows the best linear fit.} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{\fontsize{8}{7}\selectfont The plot shows ratio of the difference of Equivalent width  measured in two cases with Equivalent width measured using 2D blaze corrected spectra vs. Airmass. The red line shows the best linear fit.}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose using `floatrow` for slightly different (and looking nicer, in myopinion) layout. I also used `setspace` to change the interlineskip, – it cooperates with the `caption` package, and replaced `helvetica` with the more complete clone `TeX Gyre Heros`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin=3.5cm, top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{qhv} % TeX Gyre Heros (Helveticalclone)
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qhv} %
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize, singlespacing}, format=plain, justification=centerlast}
   \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{-2cm}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox
   {\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{airmass_vs_ew_4854_87.pdf}}{\caption{The plot shows the difference of Equivalent width measured in two cases vs. Airmass. The red line shows the best linear fit.}}

\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{airmass_vs_ew_by_ew4854_87.pdf}}{\caption{The plot shows ratio of the difference of Equivalent width measured in two cases with Equivalent width measured using 2D blaze corrected spectra vs. Airmass. The red line shows the best linear fit.}}%
\end{floatrow}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}
Some text. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext. Some more ext.

\end{document}
```

[image]